# Null pointer with self injection EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, proxy

I am using JEE7, I have a Stateless EJB that is using self injection to solve a problem with transactionality. 
When I make the call to the method *selfMethod* and it is public, everything works. If it is private, the injected components are null.
I guess it is somehow related to the proxy model and the self injection, but do not really understand why.

```
@Stateless
public class AnEjb {

    @Inject
    @EJB
    private AnEjb self;

    @Inject
    private AClass anObject;

    public void normalMethod() {
        self.selfMethod();
    }

    public/private void selfMethod() {
        anObject.anyMethod();  // Null pointer exception if selfMethod is private, no problem if it is public
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The EJB APIs provide a mechanism for self invocation:

```
    @Stateless
    public class AnEjb {

        @Resource
        private SessionContext sessionContext;

        private AnEjb self;

        @PostConstruct
        void initialise() {
            self = sessionContext.getBusinessObject(AnEjb.class);
        }

        public void normalMethod() {
            self.selfMethod();
        }

        public void selfMethod() {
            anObject.anyMethod();
        }

    }
```

Note that the `SessionContext.getBusinessObject` method returns the same "view" of the EJB that external clients will see, therefore only its public methods will be accessible.